# I cannot get my WebMethod to work in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am currently creating a webpage in C# as a school project. 
I have created a WebMethod in the file:

Default.aspx.cs

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string MyWebMethod()
    {
        return string.Format("Hello From Server");
    }
```

And the Ajax call in the file:

Default.aspx

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/MyWebMethod",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(dd, status) {
                alert('Success' + JSON.stringify(dd) + " status: " + JSON.stringify(status));
            },
            error: function(dd) {
                alert('There is error' + dd.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="test();" />
```

I have inserted a breakpoint at the start of the "MyWebMethod()", however when im debugging, the breakpoint never gets hit.

I have been sitting with this problem for about 4.5 hours now, trying every example I could find on google, and even if I download a complete example ie. "Default.aspx" and "Default.aspx.cs" files with "working" code, I cannt get it to run in my Solution.

Is there some setting you have to enable to be able to use JQuery, Ajax and WebMethods?

After I put the JSON.stringify(dd) I was able to get the error message:

```
json:{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

But after searching for a solution for several hours I have almost given up.
When I try a fix, which apparently have worked for other people with that error, it still doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Seems like you have your answer in the error message. Do you have FormsAuth or WindowsAuth or something else enabled in this project?

Comment: I don't really know. I just made a new WinForms project in VS2013 and started coding in the template.
It has the pages "Default", "About", "Contact".
How do I find out if FormsAuth or WindowsAuth is enabled?

Comment: FINALLY. I found a solution!

In the RouteConfig.cs file, you have to uncomment the line

                settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;

So it should be:

                //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;


This solved it for me!

(Apparently you can't answer your own questions when you are new)

Comment: In addition, it's unlikely that your response will come out as a JSON string. Instead it'll be XML. You should set the return type to void, then manually convert to JSON (using a library such as [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)) and write directly to the response with `Response.Write()`. Remember to set the content type.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your url path of your jquery ajax:

```
url: "Default.aspx/MyWebMethod",
```

You do not need to add .aspx to it, only to the page.

Comment: Yea sorry about that. That was just something I tried.
Its not working either way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your method is defined in a `Default.aspx` file’s code-behind, located in a folder named `"Views"`, then your url should be like this:

```
url: "/Views/Default.aspx/MyWebMethod",
```

Answer (score -1):

comment out the AutoRedirectMode in Routeconfig of App_Start folder will solve this issue

```
// settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```